# implementing subtraction with bitwise shifts and increments

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-shift

Is there an algorithm that can be use to subtract 1 from a number using only increments (`++` in C) and left bitwise shifts (`<<` in C) ?

EDIT: I am using type unsigned char

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure just use an appropriately instantiated `unsigned char result[1<<CHAR_BIT][1<<CHAR_BIT]` to look it up in. No need for `++` or `<<`!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with just the `++` operator. Loop for `UCHAR_MAX` iterations. Quite inefficient though:

```
unsigned char c = 42;
unsigned char i = 0;

while (++i)
{
    ++c;
}
// c is now equal to 41
```

<kbd>[`LIVE DEMO`](http://ideone.com/GVMUKA)</kbd>

Comment: in this case the compiler would just optimize it - so no so inefficient, just confusing

Comment: @LorenzoBelli: if you add `UCHAR_MAX` (usually 255) to an `unsigned char` then this is the same as subtracting 1, due to modulo wrap-around.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You need to approach a number n such that `n mod 255` equals `originalNumber - 1`.  The easiest way to do that would be to add 255 to your number.  This can be accomplished by 255 applications of the ++ operator or more intelligently by shifting until adds are necessary.

Edit As Requested:

```
unsigned char c = 77;
unsigned char i = 0;


if(c < 128)
{
    i = c;
    c = c << 1;
}
while(++i)
{
    ++c;
}
// c == 76
```

I realize this requires a < "operator" but lets be honest, if a computer can shift, it can less than.  Otherwise this optimization is not possible.  Bear in mind this is also going to shift a maximum of 1 time, which is still better then nothing for numbers in the range of 3-127.  In order to shift more then that, we would need a plain old + operator for our counter i.  Although...I don't know of ANY computer that can't add.

Comment: How would you use shifts to to implement addition ?

Comment: @Paul R Its a multiply by two.  It's a shortcut.  If your number is less than 128, then you can shift at least once before resulting to iterative adding.

Comment: I still don't see how you translate that to *addition* ? *Multiplication* yes, but *addition* (by a constant) doesn't seem to be possible ? (Also I think you probably mean `n mod 256`, not `n mod 255` ?)

Comment: No, I mean n mod 255.  Work out the math.  You would need some kind of counter to check if you can or cannot shift to cut down on adds.  The worst case for this would be 1.  Instead of adding 255 times, you could shift 7 times to get to 128.  Then you are guaranteed to only have 127 adds at most.  This requires extra logic however.

Comment: This means you need to test the initial value of n though, which you can't have any operators for ? And how are you going to do `mod 255` with only increments and shifts ?

Comment: There is no mod 255 going on in code.  That was the mathematical reasoning behind what the algorithm should do.  Read my answer please,  I quote "This can be accomplished by 255 applications of the ++ operator...".  If you really want to be picky, the shifting optimization is not possible without at least one of the comparison operators (such as <).

Comment: OK - I guess I still don't understand how you're going to do this with just shift and increment - maybe you could add code or pseudo code to your answer to show how this would work ?

Comment: OK - got it - thanks, and sorry to be so slow getting this. BTW the code as posted didn't actually work but it was just a simple mistake and I fixed it. +1

Answer (score 0):

This uses `+` as well, so it's not as deviously awesome as Paul R's answer.

```
unsigned char subtract_one(unsigned char value)
{
    unsigned char addend= 0;

    unsigned char old_addend;

    do
    {
        old_addend= addend;
        addend= addend << 1;
        addend++;
    }
    while (old_addend!=addend); // stops when addend==-1;

    return value + addend;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement addition using the bitwise operators as well, and then compound that with the other 2 solutions to get a solution that doesn't require the "+" operator:

```
function add(int a, int b) {
   int x, y;
   do {
       x = a & b;
       y = a ^ b;
       a = x << 1;
       b = y;
   } while (a);
   return b;
}
```